# Autofac - Can I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection's Registering Style instead of Autofac one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac, microsoft-extensions-di

We know that the registering style should look like `builder.RegisterType<EmailService1>().As<ISendEmailService>().SingleInstance();` while asp.net core built-in uses `services.AddSingleton<ISendEmailService, EmailService1>();`

I wonder if we can keep the built-in style and use Autofac as DI engine? I have a project used to use asp.net core built-in DI [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection], we want to swtich to Autofac without rewriting all register codes from built-in one to Autofac one. Is it possible?

p.s. I have installed `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and set up as document mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do all your registrations using Microsoft format if you like. Just don't try to use both syntaxes in the same registration - like if you are registering a lambda registration in Microsoft format, you can't use Autofac stuff in that lambda.

Your best way to find out if something like this is possible is to just do it. Try a little POC. You may run into things that are app-specific that don't work for one reason or another. That's not something anyone out here can predict.

Comment: Would be nice if this answer said *how* to do it.

Comment: The author already said they've set up A.E.DI as the document mentioned, which means they've [seen the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html), which include examples. The question isn't a "how" question, it's an "is this possible" question. It's possible, and the author already had it set up. There's no more "how" to show.